# What is the convention for indicating genomic primer sites?

Tags: nomenclature, gene, gene-annotation

What is the most common notation for indicating genomic binding sites of primers relative to an ORF?

For instance, if I want to indicate a primer like so:

```
...tccgccGCCCGTCCACACCCGCCGCCagctcaccATGGATGATGATATCGCCGCGCTCGT...
         [ Primer           ]        [ Hs ACTB coding sequence   ]
```

Should the location of this primer be indicated as -8 or -28 (from *ACTB* start codon) or something else?

Comment: Personally, I would say something about the forward primer spanning nucleotides -28 to -8 from the ATG codon, and perhaps give a reference to the nucleotide positions in either the genomic sequence NC_000007.14 (*ACTB* is on the reverse strand) or the mRNA sequence NM_001101.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such convention. People, mostly name their primers arbitrarily (or just FP and RP) and mention in the text about their binding sites.

In general, in the context of specific genes, the positions are described with respect to the transcription start site (TSS).